# See what files/registry keys are being accessed by application in Windows

Tags: windows, debugging, registry

How do I see what files/registry keys are being accessed by my application in Windows?

Comment: Answers regarding command-line or powershell solutions, such as whatever appears to have been used by [this WmiPrvSE.exe article](http://windows.fyicenter.com/4133_WmiPrvSE.exe_Process_on_Windows_8.html), would also be welcome.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Check out Process Monitor at

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Just forgot the name. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft Process Monitor is better at this job. I've tried other tools but they are not as good. And MS is most trustworthy in this case, since it is made by the OS developer anyway

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it myself but someone should try [Regmon](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Programming/Other-Programming-Files/Regmon.shtml) and maybe post how it goes.

Comment: It got replaced with Process Monitor.

Answer (score -1):

Check out process explorer: http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: Process Explorer doesn't do registry watching. You want Process Monitor, as mentioned above.

Comment: According to MS Process Explorer does do registry:

"Process Explorer
Find out what files, registry keys and other objects processes have open, which DLLs they have loaded, and more. This uniquely powerful utility will even show you who owns each process."